# Cast to object before null check in overriding Equals

Tags: c#, casting, null, equality

Just reading the msdn article on overriding equality operators [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(VS.80).aspx)

The following snippet confuses me...

```
// If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
if ((System.Object)p == null) // <-- wtf?
{
    return false;
}
```

Why is there a cast to `Object` here to perform the `null` comparison?

Comment: What is TwoDPoint? Maybe its a value type :-D

Comment: They have a better guideline for Visual Studio 2012. They haven't put the link in the 2005 article, so I put it here: [How to: Define Value Equality for a Type (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This must be the first time I got an answer, in the question! I solved my stack overflow problem thanks to this :]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operators apply through static analysis (and overloads), not virtual methods (overrides). With the cast, it is doing a reference equality check. Without the cast, it can run the `TwoDPoint` operator. I guess this is to avoid problems when an operator is added.

Personally, though, I'd do a reference check explicitly with `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: +1 … this style is obviously horribly confusing (this question has come up numerous times). `ReferenceEquals` exists, it should be used.

Comment: The MSDN article then goes on to explain why ReferenceEquals should be used :)

Comment: You will get a stackoverflow , like I did, when you compare your object to null `a == null`, it will rerun your overridden `==` or `!=` over and over, until it crashes.

Comment: @ppumkin however, in the code shown/linked, there *is* no `==` operator, hence my comment "when an operator is added".

Answer (score 3):

No! if you don't do that, the runtime will start a recursive call to the equality operator you are just in which results in infinite recursion and, consequently, a stack overflow.

Comment: Nope. It will not. Try the code..

Comment: Yes, without the cast it will recurse until `StackOverflow`

Answer (score 0):

To force it to use the Equals method of Object rather than its own overloaded version... just a  guess...

Answer (score 0):

This is not useless. Without that cast the == operator being overloaded would be called recursively...

Comment: Nope. I just tried the code without the cast.

Comment: @jgauffin: I had assumed that the code was overloading the == operator, instead it's overloading Equals. In this case I see no reason to do that, apart avoiding errors if the == operator is introduced later as @Marc Gravell suggests.

Comment: The point of the article is that you can't override Equals AND overload == without using a cast to Object. If you do, you get a NullReferenceException when you try to do (myVariable == null). But I agree about the use of ReferenceEquals.

Answer (score 0):

the below is the line that does the cast

```
TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint
```

the difference with the "normal" cast is that using "As" it doesn't raise an exception if the object is not "castable". In this case if "p" is not a `TwoDPoint` Type is not gonna raise an exception (cast not valid) but return null.

```
if ((System.Object)p == null) // <-- wtf? 
{ 
    return false; 
}
```

this code check if the cast went fine if not p should be null for the reason above

Comment: He asked why the `(System.Object)` cast is there, nothing else.

Comment: you are right I just misunderstood the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is the VS 2005 documentation.  I guess the folks who write the documentation also had the same question and couldn't come up with a good answer; the example was changed for VS 2008.  Here is the [current version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
{
    // If parameter is null, return false.
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(p, null))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Optimization for a common success case.
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, p))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If run-time types are not exactly the same, return false.
    if (this.GetType() != p.GetType())
        return false;

    // Return true if the fields match.
    // Note that the base class is not invoked because it is
    // System.Object, which defines Equals as reference equality.
    return (X == p.X) && (Y == p.Y);
}
```