# overloading operator== and comparison to null

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I've got a class that overloads the `operator==` to compare two objects, however when I check an object of that type against `null`, then I get a null-reference exception on the first parameter.  I wondered how I should guard against such a case, or is there another way to implement this `operator==`

```
Card c;

if (c == null) { // do something }  //null check throws exception cause c1 in operator has is a null object...

 public static bool operator ==(Card c1, Card c2)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(c1, null) )
                return false; // this does not make sense either I guess??
            return c1.Equals(c2);
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ReferenceEquals` check should do it; actually, a cheeky route can be:

```
if(((object)c1) == ((object)c2)) return true;
if(((object)c1) == null || ((object)c2) == null) return false;
return c1.Equals(c2);
```

The `(object)` casts are essentially NOPs, and just force it to perform a reference check instead of recursively hitting `==`, but also without an extra static call to `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: I always thought the ReferenceEquals was inlined (and in the end all that it does is receive the objects "as object" and compare them with ==).

Comment: @Marc Gravell, but you said 4 months earlier, that you'd use `ReferenceEquals` :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105699/152291

Comment: This answer saved my life. But remember that when one overloads "==" must also overload "!=". For this overload, the Marc answer must be implemented as             if (((object)c1) != ((object)c2)) return true;
            if (((object)c1) == null || ((object)c2) == null) return true;

Answer (score 4):

[See these guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
From that page:

> Overloaded operator == implementations should not throw exceptions.